# Crypto class PHP to objective-C

Tags: php, iphone, objective-c, class, cryptography

I have a PHP class to encrypt and decrypt strings:

```
$ralphabet = "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz1234567890,.:;?~@#\$%^&*()_+-=][}{><";
$alphabet = $ralphabet . $ralphabet;


function encrypt ($password,$strtoencrypt) {

global $ralphabet;
global $alphabet;

 for( $i=0; $i<strlen($password); $i++ )
 {
   $cur_pswd_ltr = substr($password,$i,1);
   $pos_alpha_ary[] = substr(strstr($alphabet,$cur_pswd_ltr),0,strlen($ralphabet));
  }

$i=0;
$n = 0;
$nn = strlen($password);
$c = strlen($strtoencrypt);

$encrypted_string = "";

 while($i<$c)
 {
   $encrypted_string .= substr($pos_alpha_ary[$n],strpos($ralphabet,substr($strtoencrypt,$i,1)),1);

   $n++;
   if($n==$nn) $n = 0;
   $i++;
  }

return $encrypted_string;

}
```

It receives the string to encrypt, and a KEY.

I need to translate it to objective-C, but I don't understand PHP much.

What are the equivalents to the functions that are used in the PHP class, so that I can create the class in objective-C?

Comment: I can't help you with the translation (as I only know the PHP side), but that code is using some form of the [`Vigenère cipher`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vigen%C3%A8re_cipher). Perhaps Google can help now you know what it's called?

Comment: substring, string index search, string length, for loop, and while loop.  this is pretty straightforward.  why don't you try changing to pseudocode first if you having a hard time?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All the functions you can find in this code come directly from the C side of PHP, doing man theFunction will give you all the informations you need about them.

Comment: Hi, i can't find out the correspondent methods of: substr, strstr, strpos.
Anyone?

Comment: @Rui Lopes: You want NSString's `-rangeOfString:` and `-substringWithRange:`

Answer (score 0):

30 seconds in Google led me to [this](http://php.net/manual/en/function.substr.php), I suppose if you invest a little time you can find the docs for the rest of the functions.